# libgdx. make Texture to Show/Hide/setVisible in android

Tags: android, libgdx, textures, visible

I want the Texture to set visible or not. So that I can show one texture when other is hidden or set false on visible.. how do I do it? In render method.

Something like:

```
Texture tex = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("and.jpg");
tex.show or tex.hide
```

Or tell me a method to flip an image horizontally in render method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a texture region of it and flip it.

```
TextureRegion tr=new TextureRegion(tex);

tr.flip(true,false); // this will flip the textureregion only horizontally, write this code again to flip it back!
```

Now draw your texture region.

```
batch.draw(tr,x,y);
```

If you want to show and hide your texture create a boolean variable.

```
boolean showTextureRegion=true;
```

In your draw method will be like

```
if(showTextureRegion)
 batch.draw(tr,x,y);
```

And to hide it just make the showTextureRegion true.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used boolean data type idea. Flipping an image in render method makes it flip too much times. Left Right Left Right Left Right... now its working.

Comment: Of course, because is flipping it each frame, you don't want that! Flip it only when you need it